# Hatch boundary problem in tikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem to create the hatch in the right wall of the next figure
[image]

I want it with the same hatch as the left one and with the c1 damper and k1 spring connected to the left wall. I already tried with this code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,fit,matrix}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\let\savestar\star
\renewcommand\star{{\scalerel*{\bigstar}{\savestar}}}%Para escalar los símbolos
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.2cm,post length=0.2cm,segment length=6}] 
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,  
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {}; % Minimum width es el ancho de los amortiguadores,minimum height es la separación en el amortiguador
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$); 
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]

\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm]


\node (M) [draw,outer sep=0pt,thick,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm] {$m_1$};
\node (M2) [draw,outer sep=0pt,thick,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm] at (2,0) {$m_2$};


\node (ground) [ground,anchor=north,yshift=-0.25cm,minimum width=5.5cm,xshift=1cm] at (M.south) {};
\draw (ground.north west) -- (ground.north east) -- (ground.south east) -- (ground.south west);

\node (fill) [ground,xshift=-0.15cm,minimum height = 0.3cm, minimum width = 0.3cm] at (ground.west) {};

\node (fill2) [xshift=-0.15cm,minimum height = 0.3cm, minimum width = 0.3cm] at (ground.east) {};

\draw (fill.north west) -- (fill.south west) -- (fill.south east); 

\draw [thick] (M.south west) ++ (0.2cm,-0.125cm) circle (0.125cm)  (M.south east) ++ (-0.2cm,-0.125cm) circle (0.125cm);
\draw [thick] (M2.south west) ++ (0.2cm,-0.125cm) circle (0.125cm)  (M2.south east) ++ (-0.2cm,-0.125cm) circle (0.125cm);

\node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2.5cm,anchor=south east] at (fill.north west) {};
\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west) -- (wall.south west) -- (wall.south east);

\node (wall2) [rotate=-90, minimum width=2.5cm,anchor=south east] at (fill2.north west) {};
\draw (wall2.north east) -- (wall2.north west) -- (wall2.south west) -- (wall2.south east);

%\draw [spring] (M.220) -- ($(M.north east)!(wall.-4)!(wall.south west)$);
\draw [spring] (M.220) -- (-1.5,-0.45);
\draw [spring] (M2.220) -- ($(M.north east)!(M.220)!(M.south east)$);
\draw [spring] (3.5,-0.45) -- (2.5,-0.45);

\draw [damper] (M.170) -- (-1.5,0.1);
\draw [damper] (M2.170) -- ($(M.north east)!(M2.170)!(M.south east)$);
\draw [damper] (3.5,0.1) -- (2.5,0.1);

\node at (-1,.8) {$c_1$};
\node at (1,.8) {$c_2$};
\node at (3,.8) {$c_3$};

\node at (-1,-.8) {$k_1$};
\node at (1,-.8) {$k_2$};
\node at (3,-.8) {$k_3$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This adds the pattern on the wall and simplifies some things. Further improvements are possible, using `quotes` here may not be one of them.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.2cm,post
length=0.2cm,segment length=6}}, 
damper/.style={thick,decoration={markings,  
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {}; % Minimum width es el ancho de los amortiguadores,minimum height es la separación en el amortiguador
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$); 
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate}]]

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=One-should-not-use-tikzstyle]
 \node (M) [draw,outer sep=0pt,thick,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm] {$m_1$};
 \node (M2) [draw,outer sep=0pt,thick,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm] at (2,0) {$m_2$};

 \draw [thick] (M.south west) ++ (0.2cm,-0.125cm) circle[radius=0.125cm]  (M.south east) ++ (-0.2cm,-0.125cm) circle[radius=0.125cm];
 \draw [thick] (M2.south west) ++ (0.2cm,-0.125cm) circle[radius=0.125cm]  (M2.south east) ++ (-0.2cm,-0.125cm) circle[radius=0.125cm];
 \draw [spring] (M.220) -- node[below=0.2ex]{$k_1$} ++ (-1,0);
 \draw [spring] (M2.220) -- node[below=0.2ex]{$k_2$} ($(M.north east)!(M.220)!(M.south east)$);
 \draw [spring] (M2.-40) -- node[below=0.2ex]{$k_3$} ++ (1,0);

 \draw [damper] (M.170) -- node[above=1em]{$c_1$} ++ (-1,0);
 \draw [damper] (M2.170) --  node[above=1em]{$c_2$}($(M.north east)!(M2.170)!(M.south east)$);
 \draw [damper] (M2.10) --  node[above=1em]{$c_3$} ++ (1,0);
\end{scope}
\draw[pattern=north east lines,thick] ([xshift=-5mm]One-should-not-use-tikzstyle.north west)
-| (One-should-not-use-tikzstyle.south west) -|
(One-should-not-use-tikzstyle.north east) -|
([xshift=5mm,yshift=-5mm]One-should-not-use-tikzstyle.south east) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Schrödinger´s cat, certainly your code produces the hatch in the right wall, as desired; however it does not connect the c1 damper and k1 spring to the left wall. I already tried to find where to modify it, however I have not find yet how to get it.

Comment: @Alfredo Use `\draw[pattern=north east lines,thick] ([xshift=-5mm]One-should-not-use-tikzstyle.north west)
-| (One-should-not-use-tikzstyle.south west) -|
(One-should-not-use-tikzstyle.north east) -|
([xshift=5mm,yshift=-5mm]One-should-not-use-tikzstyle.south east) -| cycle;`.